# Free Multimedia Projection Software

Tags: windows, linux, video, media-player

I'm an organizer of a film festival. We will have the film festival gala in the next days.

At the gala, we will show up with a big video projector some of the movies, some intros etc. We are using a laptop connected by VGA to the projector.

If I use VLC or other video player then I need to make a playlist or to open these movies separately but it will show the mouse cursor and the Desktop etc. I want to make it looks professional.

**It must be live edited. Like on the laptop screen click on movie play and see it on the projector.**

Is there any free multimedia projection software which will help me?

Comment: Make sure that the laptop supports multiple displays - set the projector as one and use VLC display full screen on that one while dealing with the playlists, etc., on the laptop display.